# Is there a null handler to string method at c#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, null, isnull

I am able to assign a variable like below:

```
if (Session["myVariable"] != null)
{
    string variAble = Session["myVariable"].ToString();
}
```

Is there a method which checks whether an object is null or not and then assign if it is not null?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: ye but it does not handle other objects such as session. if the object you are comparing is string it works.

Comment: Why this method does not suitable for you?

Comment: so if the value is null you dont want to assign the variable at all, or provide a default value? could you write some puedo code on how you want this to work

Comment: @sa_ddam213 if you don't make that null check comparison your application would throw error if that session is null. so i am looking for a method that would do session null check and if not null assign to string like string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: So your looking for a method that is exactly the same as the method you are using? what I am asking is how you are expecting to use it in your code, as the code you have now is perfectly fine, or is it not? eg: if the session object is null what do you want to assign to you variable, or are you not even going to assign it?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 it is fine but always looking for better solutions. for example TheEvilPenguin solution is new to me and looks pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string variAble = Session["myVariable"] ?? "";`

**EDIT** A slightly more robust form, as suggested by @hatchet, is:

`string variAble = (Session["myVariable"] ?? "").ToString();`

Comment: If he needed to do the ToString, then `= (Session["myVariable"] ?? "").ToString();`

Comment: @ReedCopsey - that can be handled with the slight modification in my comment above.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I thought if Session[] returns an object (or boxed value type), then that would work since all object descendants have ToString.

Comment: @hatchet but it returns it as a string, not an int, etc.  That was what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't anything new, you can use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to potentially simplify this:

```
string variable = Session["myVariable"] != null ? Session["myVariable"].ToString() : "Fallback";
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Nope - always been there.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extension method, as those still work with null objects.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static String ToNullString(this object o)
    {
        return o == null ? "" : o.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would consider it poor form though - it'll be confusing to whoever will be supporting the code after you, or even to you a few months down the track.  It's probably better to just do the null check.

Comment: but i suppose this would not be entire application wide am i incorrect ? can i define an extension method for entire asp.net website ?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin, `StringExtensions` will have to be a static class

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG As long as you include the namespace the class is in, you'll be able to use it anywhere that references the assembly it's in

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks.  That's what I get for not compiling code before I post it

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin instead of me to go each existing page and add reference can i add it globally somehow ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Yes, you can create the class once in a regular .cs file (in AppCode if my memory is correct) and then make sure you include the namespace in any file you want to use it in.  It's been a while since I've done any ASP.NET, and that was ASP.NET MVC, but I know I did something like this.

Comment: thanks it works. but i have to call it as ToNullString . can't i still call it as ToString ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You can call it ToString, but then `Object`'s ToString() method will still be called when you try to use it.  You can call it anything you want except methods which exist on the types you want to use it on.

Comment: can i also make it like this. for example that extension method returns a value "". Can i make it like if the right side of object is null, just pass it. so don't change the left side variable value. like my main example. if the object is null it will pass and won't assign a new value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22936/discussion-between-theevilpenguin-and-monstermmorpg)